# PHP: Number of rows actually changed after mssql UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, mysql_affected_rows() tells me how many rows in a table where changed after a MySQL UPDATE statement. It only counts rows where values actually changed.

The MSSQL equivalent, mssql_rows_affected(), however, returns the number of rows where the WHERE clause of the UPDATE statement is true, even if nothing in those rows actually changes.

Is there a way to determine the number of rows that were actually changed in MSSQL?

Comment: I don't understand. Surely if the WHERE clause evaluates to true, then the row is UPDATEd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a clause to your WHERE condition to not update a row if it doesn't change:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET foo = 'bar'
WHERE yourcondition
AND foo <> bar
```

Comment: Works great, only needed an additional clause to handle the case where foo is NULL.NULL <> bar returns false and so lines that contain NULL never update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_affected_rows

```
int mysql_affected_rows ([ resource $link_identifier ] )
```

More information at : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php